# wait for completing operation in awesomium in C#

Tags: c#, awesomium

i'm developing an app using awesomium and c#

look at this line of code:

```
browser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("rand()");
```

when this line execute, the webpage says "Please wait..." and a image with low opacity shown , and can't click or run any script until a few seconds

is there any way to wait for this action in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this..

```
 int Sec = 1000;  // 1 sec 1000ms
    int i = 0 ;
    do{
       //do application events
      Application.DoEvents();
       //sleep for 1 mili second 
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
      i++;  //increase i by 1 milisecond

    }while((Sec*5) > i );
```

// here you can do something after wating..

Comment: welcom ! you can also check for "Please wait..." element in while loop...using Javascript.. if "Please wait..." is vanished then come out the while loop.... if you negate "can't click or run any script until a few seconds"